# Adding Category Name as H1 woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I have looked everywhere and I cannot figure this out.

I am wanting my category name as a H1 tag to be above the product listings on the category page.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. By adding the code below to the file

plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php

```
<?php if ( is_product_category() || is_product() ) : ?>
   <div class="page-header-image generate-page-header category-header">
       <div class="grid-container"><h1><?php single_term_title(); ?></h1></div>
</div> 
<?php endif; ?>
```